# Do regression algorithms give you a probability associated to the predicted value?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, probability

I am looking for an algorithm to predict an amount of money (a real value), therefore I am thinking of using a regression algorithm. However, I also need to know the probability associated to that value, i.e. Customer A will spend $50 tomorrow with probability 65%.

Which regression algorithms give you that probability for each prediction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The most common framework for regression is to suppose that observed values are equal to a deterministic function F(x) plus "random" (more accurately, unexplained or unmodeled) noise. Therefore the uncertainty in a predicted value is equal to the uncertainty from parameter estimates plus the unexplained noise.

The unexplained noise is typically modeled as Gaussian with mean zero. The mean square error after training is an estimate of the variance of the noise. The uncertainty due to parameter estimates is harder to come by. There are formulas which can be derived for linear regression and applied to nonlinear models with a certain amount of hand-waving. Probably a simpler, and more broadly applicable approach is via random sampling: construct an ensemble of models by training from random subsets of the training data, and let the uncertainty due to parameters be just the distribution of outputs of the ensemble.

The total uncertainty would then be the parameter uncertainty plus the noise estimate. From that you can construct any intervals you want.

That said, this question is probably more suitable for stats.stackexchange.com.